# Method not found using StackExchange.Redis

Tags: c#, stackexchange.redis

I'm trying to implement Redis caching in our sitecore setup, but I'm having trouble doing so. We are running dotnet framwork 4.8 in a containerized setup.
I've install StackExchange.Redis Nuget package version 2.7.27, and I'm trying to write to the cahce using `db.StringSet(applicationCacheKeyEnum.ToString(), objectJsonString, TimeSpan.MaxValue, true, When.Always);`. My code compiles, but at runtime I get the following error:

```
{
"Message": "An error has occurred.",
"ExceptionMessage": "Method not found: 'Boolean StackExchange.Redis.IDatabase.StringSet(StackExchange.Redis.RedisKey, StackExchange.Redis.RedisValue, System.Nullable`1<System.TimeSpan>, Boolean, StackExchange.Redis.When, StackExchange.Redis.CommandFlags)'.",
"ExceptionType": "System.MissingMethodException",
"StackTrace": "......"}
```

As far as I can see the signature of my method call matches Redis' StringSet() method, so I don't understand why this is happening. Below is the method in which I'm trying to set the cache value:

```
    public void AddToCache(ApplicationCacheKeyEnum applicationCacheKeyEnum, object theObject)
{
    IDatabase db = _redisAccessor.Redis.GetDatabase(0);
    string objectJsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(theObject, Formatting.Indented);
    db.StringSet(applicationCacheKeyEnum.ToString(), objectJsonString, TimeSpan.MaxValue, true, When.Always);
}
```

Contents of Packages.Props:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project 
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
<PropertyGroup>
    <PlatformVersion>10.3.0</PlatformVersion>
</PropertyGroup>
<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Update="Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc" 
Version="5.2.4" />
    <PackageReference Update="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization" 
Version="1.1.3" />
    <PackageReference Update="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client" 
Version="5.2.6" />
    <PackageReference Update="Microsoft.AspNet.Razor" 
Version="3.2.7" />
    <PackageReference Update="Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages" 
Version="3.2.7" />
    <PackageReference Update="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi" 
Version="5.2.9" />
    <PackageReference Update="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core" 
Version="5.2.9" />
    <PackageReference Update="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.WebHost" 
Version="5.2.9" />
    <PackageReference Update="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors" 
Version="5.2.6" />
    <PackageReference 
Update="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform" V 
ersion="3.6.0" />
    <PackageReference 
Update="Microsoft.CrmSdk.XrmTooling.CoreAssembly" 
Version="9.1.0.110" />
    <PackageReference 
Update="Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.StackExchangeRedis" 
Version="6.0.0.0" />
    <PackageReference 
Update="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions" 
Version="6.0.0.0" />
    <PackageReference 
Update="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection" 
Version="6.0.0.0" />
    <PackageReference 
Update="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions" 
Version="6.0.0.0" />
    <PackageReference 
Update="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions" 
Version="6.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Update="Microsoft.Extensions.Http" 
Version="2.1.1" />
    <PackageReference 
Update="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory" 
Version="4.5.0" />
    <PackageReference 
Update="Microsoft.IdentityModel.JsonWebTokens" Version="5.4.0" 
/>
    <PackageReference 
Update="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect" 
Version="5.3.0" />
    <PackageReference Update="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols" 
Version="5.3.0" />
    <PackageReference Update="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens" 
Version="5.4.0" />
    <PackageReference Update="Microsoft.Xrm.Client.2015" 
Version="7.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Update="Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure" 
Version="1.0.0" />

    <PackageReference Update="jose-jwt" Version="2.5.0" />
    <PackageReference Update="ExpressiveAnnotations" 
Version="2.9.6" />
    <PackageReference Update="RestSharp" Version="106.15.0" />
    <PackageReference Update="RestSharp" Version="105.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Update="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="13.0.1" 
/>
    <PackageReference Update="jose-jwt" Version="2.5.0"/>
    <PackageReference Update="ExpressiveAnnotations" 
Version="2.9.6"/>
    <PackageReference Update="FluentResults" Version="3.0.0" />
    
    <PackageReference Update="System.Text.Encodings.Web" 
Version="6.0.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Update="System.Memory" Version="4.5.2" />
    <PackageReference Update="System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt" 
Version="5.4.0" />
    <PackageReference 
Update="System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe" Version="5.0.0" 
/>

    <PackageReference Update="Sitecore.Kernel" 
Version="$(PlatformVersion)" />
    <PackageReference Update="Sitecore.Mvc" 
Version="$(PlatformVersion)" />
    <PackageReference Update="Sitecore.ExperienceEditor" 
Version="$(PlatformVersion)" />
    <PackageReference Update="Sitecore.ExperienceEditor.Speak" 
Version="$(PlatformVersion)" />
    <PackageReference Update="Sitecore.Assemblies.Platform" 
Version="$(PlatformVersion)" />
    <PackageReference Update="Sitecore.ContentSearch" 
Version="$(PlatformVersion)" />
    <PackageReference Update="Sitecore.ContentSearch.Linq" 
Version="$(PlatformVersion)" />
    <PackageReference Update="Sitecore.ExperienceForms" 
Version="$(PlatformVersion)" />
    <PackageReference Update="Sitecore.ExperienceForms.Mvc" 
Version="$(PlatformVersion)" />
    <PackageReference Update="Sitecore.Logging" 
Version="$(PlatformVersion)" />
    <PackageReference Update="Sitecore.Services.Infrastructure" 
Version="$(PlatformVersion)" />
    <PackageReference Update="Sitecore.LayoutService" 
Version="9.0.310" />
    <PackageReference 
Update="Sitecore.Assemblies.SitecoreHeadlessServicesServer" 
Version="21.0.583" />
    <PackageReference Update="Sitecore.Framework.Conditions" 
Version="6.0.0" />
    <PackageReference 
Update="Sitecore.Framework.Rules.Abstractions" Version="6.0.0" 
/>

    <PackageReference Update="Helpfulcore.Caching" 
Version="1.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Update="Helpfulcore.Caching.Sitecore" 
Version="1.0.4" />
    <PackageReference Update="Helpfulcore.Caching.Sitecore.Core" 
Version="1.0.2" />

    <PackageReference Update="xWrap.Framework" Version="1.0.21" 
/>
    <PackageReference Update="xWrap.Mvc.Framework" 
Version="1.0.21" />

    <PackageReference Update="Configy" Version="1.0.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Update="Kamsar.WebConsole" 
Version="2.0.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Update="MicroCHAP" Version="1.2.2.2" />
    <PackageReference Update="Rainbow" Version="2.1.4.0" />
    <PackageReference Update="Rainbow.Storage.Sc" 
Version="2.1.4.0" />
    <PackageReference Update="Rainbow.Storage.Yaml" 
Version="2.1.4.0" />
    <PackageReference Update="Unicorn" Version="4.1.6.0" />
    <PackageReference Update="Unicorn.Roles" Version="4.1.6.0" 
/>
    <PackageReference Update="Unicorn.Users" Version="4.1.6.0" 
/>

    <PackageReference Update="MSTest.TestAdapter" 
Version="3.1.1"/>
    <PackageReference Update="MSTest.TestFramework" 
Version="3.1.1"/>
    <PackageReference Update="Moq" Version="4.20.69"/>
    <PackageReference Update="StackExchange.Redis" 
Version="2.7.27" />
</ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

In csproj file i have the following ItemGroup:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Sitecore.Assemblies.Platform">
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc" />
    <PackageReference Include="Sitecore.Kernel" />
    <PackageReference Include="Sitecore.Mvc" />
    <PackageReference Include="StackExchange.Redis" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

Can anyone help me understand, what causes the error?

Comment: "I've install StackExchange.Redis Nuget package version x.x.x.x" - I'd be surprised if "x.x.x.x" is actually the version you're using, and seeing as this is very likely to be a versioning problem, the *actual* version is really important.

Comment: Additionally, if you could provide a [mcve] so that others could reproduce the problem, that would make a *huge* difference.

Comment: @JonSkeet You're right, of course, about the version number. I menat to get the exact version number before posting, but forgot, sorry - i've edited the question

Comment: Okay, that's a start. Now for more information - are you able to run the code when it's *not* containerized? What projects are involved? Basically the more information you can provide - again, ideally a [mcve] - the more likely it is that we can help you.

Comment: As @JonSkeet said - try providing a [mre] or at least share contents of relevant .csproj files.

Comment: Try updating `Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.StackExchangeRedis` to `6.0.27` version.

Comment: @JonSkeet I'm not really sure how to provide a minimal reproducible example of a containerized Sitecore installation

Comment: @Lasserh: I'd *first* try to reproduce it without containerization and without Sitecore at all. You're accessing Redis, right? That should be feasible without Sitecore being involved, right? Try to reduce the scope of where the problem *could* be one step at a time.